# Explanation required: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException:

Tags: spring

when i try to access beans in following way

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("factoryMethodDemo.xml");
    System.out.println(context.getBean("bean2",BeanLifeCycle.class));
    System.out.println(context.getBean("bean",FactoryMethodDemo.class));
    context.close();
```

Here BeanLifeCycle.class implements all the lifecycle interfaces like BeanNameAware...DisposableBean etc.
FactoryMethodDemo.class is a simple bean

FactoryMethodDemo.java

```
        package com.demo;

    import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class FactoryMethodDemo {
        private String message;

        public FactoryMethodDemo() {
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("setMessage Called");
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void defaultInit() {
            System.out.println("defaultInit");

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("factoryMethodDemo.xml");
            System.out.println(context.getBean("bean2",BeanLifeCycle.class));
            System.out.println(context.getBean("&bean",FactoryMethodDemo.class));
            context.close();
        }
    }
```

BeanLifeCycle.java

```
        package com.demo;

    import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

    public class BeanLifeCycle implements BeanNameAware, BeanFactoryAware, ApplicationContextAware, BeanPostProcessor, InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

        private String property;

        public void setProperty(String property) {
            System.out.println("setProperty");
        }

        @Override
        public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("setBeanFactory");
        }

        @Override
        public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
            System.out.println("setBeanName");
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("setApplicationContext");

        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization");
            return new Object();
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization");
            return new Object();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            // THis is treated as init method
            System.out.println("afterPropertiesSet");
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("destroy");
        }


    }
```

**factoryMethodDemo.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" x        mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="bean" class="com.demo.FactoryMethodDemo">
    <property name="message" value="message"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="bean2" class="com.demo.BeanLifeCycle">
    <property name="property" value="property"></property></bean>
    </beans>
```

It throws following exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'bean' must be of type [com.demo.FactoryMethodDemo], but was actually of type [java.lang.Object]

obviously Object type is returned instead of FactoryMethodDemo, an someone please explain what is happening behind the scene to cause such exception.
Thank you for your time & help in advance

Comment: Updated post with the BeanLifeCycleDemo.java & FactoryMethodDemo.java codes

Comment: It boils down to BeanPostProcessor... BeanLifeCycle class is implementing BeanPostProcessor which is causing exception, i am returning new Object() in postProcessAfterInitialization(...) & postProcessBeforeInitialization(...) returning arg0 solved the problem. I will be reading about BeanPostProcessor in detail... by that time if someone could explain it then it would be helpful for someone facing same problem & landing on this post... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `com.demo.FactoryMethodDemo` will implement the [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) interface:

This means that the bean will not be available for lookup in the application context as the `FactoryMethodDemo` bean is responsible for creating another bean (with id `bean`).

If you look at the implementation of `FactoryMethodDemo` you'll most likely see that there is an implementation of `getObject` which will return an instance of the bean that will be available with id `bean`.

Because a "factory bean" is different from normal beans, you won't be able to look it up using the `getBean(String beanId, Class beanType)` method, as it won't be registered.  You should however be able to do the following:

```
context.getBean("&bean");
```

this will return the "factory" that created the bean "bean".

See also [Spring Reference Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

Comment: Hello beny23, FactoryMethodDemo.class is just a plain bean sorry for the misleading class name, i was trying to learn how to implement the factory method in springs hence created the class with given name, but as i encountered the exception i stripped everything & had the class as a simple bean, but still had the same exception. I have updated the post with both java classes.I think its something with BeanLifeCycle class implementing all the life cycle interfaces. If i strip off all the interfaces implementation from BeanLifeCycle, the code runs normally.